# Superlative + noun / Superlative + of + noun

Tags: prepositions, superlatives

Is there any difference in meaning in the following examples? (with or without "of")

> 1- He comes from one of ***the grandest of*** Palestinian families.
>
> 1'- He comes from one of ***the grandest*** Palestinian families.(Is it
>   possible to use this version?)
>
> 2- I will continue to seek out the ***grandest of*** restaurants. ( Is he
>   trying to find one restaurant or more than one restaurant? I am
>   not sure about it. Can we know it without further context?)
>
> 2'- I will continue to seek out the ***grandest*** restaurants. (More than one I think?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of these forms is acceptable, and the meaning of the "grandest" forms is not significantly different from the "grandest of".

> I will continue to seek out the grandest of restaurants.

could be used if the speaker is looking for the very best restaurant in the world, or merely those in the top tier.

> I will continue to seek out the grandest restaurants.

seems to pretty clearly indicate a search for multiple restaurants.